# SQL Developer is not starting without errors

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to run SQL Developer that is installed on a cloud repository (called Box), and it's not even starting.

FYI, I've installed another SQL Developer on my local repository. Would that be a problem?
Also, I've checked that sqldelvoper.conf is referring ../../jdk location.

OS: Windows 10

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're renting space from BOX, a storage cloud provider, and you put the SQL Developer archive THERE, and you're trying to run it from your local machine?

I guess you're using the BOX Drive feature?

If you open a CMD window on your local machine, and try to start the program EXE or SH, what do you see?

I will say, even if you did get this working, you would not be happy. It would most likely be intolerably slow, esp when you wanted to open or save a file.